# ROS Answers SE migration: Error in urdf

Tags: ros, urdf, xml, urdf-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to do the urdf tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Create%20your%20own%20urdf%20file
So when i launch `rosrun urdfdom check_urdf my_robot.urdf` (I'm in groovy)
I get this error

```
Error:   Could not find the 'robot' element in the xml file
         at line 59 in /tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-urdfdom-0.2.8-2precise-20140305-0755/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
ERROR: Model Parsing the xml failed
```

However the element robot is there in the first line

```
<robot name="Mark1">

  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.36 0.376 0.2"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.7 0 0"/>
      <material name="white">
        <color rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
  
  <link name="lwheel">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.028" radius="0.0625"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <material name="black">
        <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
  
  <joint name="base_to_lwheel" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="lwheel"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0.162 0" rpy="-1.5708 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  
  <link name="rwheel">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.028" radius="0.0625"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <material name="black">
        <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
  
  <joint name="base_to_rwheel" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="rwheel"/>
    <origin xyz="0 -0.162 0" rpy="1.5708 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  
  <link name="laser">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.015 0.045 0.015"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.022 0 0.015"/>
      <material name="black">
        <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
  
  <joint name="base_to_scanner" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="laser"/>
    <origin xyz="0.2 0 0.6125" rpy="0 0 0"/>

  
</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188007/error-in-urdf/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your final `<joint>` tag is missing its close tag - perhaps that's preventing the XML parser from parsing the file properly?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-29**:
It works!!! Thank you